# Copy all occurencies with a specific pattern in to a list to a different file

Tags: powershell

I have a json-formatted file that contains a number of lines starting with *"url": "someValue",* with spacing before, like this:

```
      "url": "http://www.mydomain.som/assets/js/lib/less-1.2.1.min.js",
```

Could someone answer how I could extract all those lines and copy the to another file and sort that list alphabetically with a Powershell command? I have just started using Powershell and have no clue how to do this and would be very grateful if someone could answer this.

/Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-Content .\json.txt | 
Where-Object {$_ -match '"url": "http://www.mydomain.som/.+",'} |
Set-Content .\URLs.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Shay, that helped me. I just added Sort-Object to get the list sorted as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not Powershell but following command could be all it takes.

```
type YourFile | find "url" | sort > YourNewfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-Content "c:\MyFilePath.txt") |
    foreach { $_ -match '"url":/s*"http:(.*?)"," } |
    Set-Content "c:\MyFilteredList.txt"
```

You might have to tweak the regular expression (not tested).